# Dynamic Array Size and crashing at getline();

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, size

I've been working on a program recently that takes names as inputs and will eventually sort & binary search them. However upon attempting to make the array a dynamic size (that would increase by one with each loop iteration), it ran into various issues.

I can make the string array composed of 20 elements and the program works, but the extra credit for my assignment is to make it a dynamic size. Currently the program crashes without any sort of error code once it reaches "getline(cin, Names[x]);". *I've been searching around and I know it'd be easier to do a vector instead of an array in this case, however I don't believe I'm allowed to use vectors on this assignment.*

Thanks

**Original Code**

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void main()
{
    int x = 0;
    string * Names = new string[x];
    bool NameInputEnd(0);

    cout << "    Enter your names to be sorted\n";
    cout << "To exit just press [Enter] at any time\n";

    do
    {
        cout << x << endl;
        cout << "\n< Name " << (x + 1) << " > = ";

        !!**CRASHES HERE**!!

        getline(cin, Names[x]);

        if (Names[x].empty() || x == 19)
        {
            cout << "\nFinal Name Amount = " << (x + 1) << endl << endl;
            NameInputEnd = 1;
            continue;
        }

        x++;

    } while (NameInputEnd == 0);

    delete [] Names;
}
```

**Changes**

```
int tempsize(1), x(0);
string * Names = new string[tempsize];
...

do
{
...
    x++;
    tempsize++;
}while (NameInputEnd == 0);
```

Comment: Think about what the value of `x` is when you use `string * Names = new string[x];`.  How many elements have you just made(value of `x`)?  Also I suggest you switch to using a `std::vector`.

Comment: Oh, I understand now that I was setting the array to having a size of 0 elements, which is invalid from what I saw searching. I now created a temporary variable to substitute in, which is set to 1 initially, growing by 1 simultaneously with x in each loop iteration.

Comment: Arrays can't grow once they are created. Incrementing `x` won't magically increase the size of the array. You should either allocate enough space first (`string *Names = new string[20];`) or use `std::vector` - which can grow in size.

Comment: Is that working?  If not please update the question and the code.

Comment: Updated to the changes I made, it now receives an error on the 4th iteration through the loop, which I don't quite understand.  
     
So there's no possible way arrays can grow in size at all after they're created? In that case maybe the extra credit wants me to make the arrays into vectors. Upon which case does anyone have any recommended pages I could check out? I'm not particularly familiar with vectors unfortunately.

Comment: Would changing the following two lines in the original code perhaps solve the problem? `if (Names[x].empty() || x == 19)` into `if (Names[x].empty())` and `x++` into `Names->resize(++x)`? This seems to work for me in unix (osx) with `std=gnu++11`.

Comment: Woops, the "x == 19" line wasn't supposed to be in that version of the program, my bad. However I made both changes and it still crashes after entering in name #3. 

It'll cycle through Names 1, 2, 3, and right after 3 it crashes before getting to name 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array cannot be resized once it has been created.  You have to destroy it and create a new array with a copy of the existing data.  For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    int x = 0;
    int capacity = 20;
    string * Names = new string[capacity];
    string Name;

    cout << "    Enter your names to be sorted\n";
    cout << "To exit just press [Enter] at any time\n";

    do
    {
        cout << x << endl;
        cout << "\n< Name " << (x + 1) << " > = ";

        if ((!getline(cin, Name)) || Name.empty())
            break;

        if (x == capacity)
        {
            int newCapacity = capacity + 20;
            string *newNames = new string[newCapacity];
            copy(Names, Names + x, newNames);
            delete [] Names;
            Names = newNames;
            capacity = newCapacity;
        }

        Names[x] = Name;
        ++x;    
    }
    while (true);

    cout << "\nFinal Name Amount = " << x << endl << endl;

    delete [] Names;
}
```

You really should use a `std::vector`, though:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    vector<string> Names;
    string Name;

    Names.reserve(20); // optional

    cout << "    Enter your names to be sorted\n";
    cout << "To exit just press [Enter] at any time\n";

    do
    {
        cout << Names.size() << endl;
        cout << "\n< Name " << (Names.size() + 1) << " > = ";

        if ((!getline(cin, Name)) || Name.empty())
            break;

        Names.push_back(Name);
    }
    while (true);

    cout << "\nFinal Name Amount = " << Names.size() << endl << endl;
}
```

Comment: This not only fixed it, but also really helped me understand various syntax way more. There really is a lot of errors I make in my coding, I have a lot to touch up on. Thanks Mr Lebeau